# Want to Consume Web Service but "cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, web-services, apache, http

I have the following Imports

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;

import com.sshtools.j2ssh.net.HttpResponse;
```

---

---

And inside my main method, the following code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://vogellac2dm.appspot.com/register");
try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registrationid", "123456789"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

---

To get the httpclient imports to locate the package, I had to download the JAR file from [java2s.com link here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonshttpclientjar.htm)

But I still have multiple errors on

> HttpPost cannot be resolved to a type
>
> BasicNameValuePair cannot be resolved to a type
>
> UrlEncodedFormEntity cannot be resolved to a type

---

---

It is a Ruby on Rails web service, and I need to be able to:

1. Create an object of a specific type, which is defined in the WSDL.
2. Call the service, and receive back the type into my newly defined
   object.

And unfortunately I'm not very seasoned in Java development.  So please keep that in mind :)

Examples and direction greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You definitely need the jar, but where have you put it to compile/run your application? It should be on the classpath. This is a java compilation error, nothing to do with the RoR.

Comment: Project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add Externals JARs...

Comment: Yeah, you're missing jars. HttpPost is not in that jar, nor are the other two. Sec, I'm looking for it.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance here.. but what exactly should i do? =-\

Comment: Download the binaries from [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) in a zip. Under lib, you'll find a bunch of jars. Add those like the others.

Comment: In addition to the errors already pointed out, you are importing the wrong `HttpResponse` class, and using `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`. You should really start with a simpler project if you are a beginning Java programmer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on which library to use.  Unfortunately "starting with a simpler project" isn't an option for me.  I have a matter of days before I need to have this working.  Love last minute changes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `X cannot be resolved to a type` occurs when you are missing import statements and the compiler cannot find the type on the classpath. This means you are missing a number of class files from your classpath.

The classes `HttpPost`, `BasicNameValuePair`, `UrlEncodedFormEntity` are all part of [`Apache HttpComponents`](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

Download the binaries/source. In the zip, you will find the jars you need to add to your classpath. With Eclipse, you do this by adding the jars (as external jars) to your project build path.